# Syntax error when importing an excel file into a jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble importing an excel file into a Jupyter notebook. I keep getting a syntax error on the last quotation mark. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r "C:\Users\kabir\Documents\Data Science Projects\datasets\Body Fat Data_2016.xls")

File "<ipython-input-13-94de2d4a3dec>", line 2
data = pd.read_excel(r "C:\Users\kabir\Documents\Data Science Projects\datasets\Body Fat Data_2016.xls")
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\kabir\Documents\Data Science Projects\datasets\Body Fat Data_2016.xls")
```

You can't put a space between the `r` and the `"` for a raw string.